# C: Output of SHA-1 as little endian to float

Tags: c, endianness, sha

As per [this documentation](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0392.html#algorithm-angle), my task is to compute a colour value based on an alphanumeric identifierer. The idea is to run the identifier string through a SHA-1 and use parts of the result to compute the colour values.

I am having trouble with the following step:

> Treat the output as little endian and extract the last-significant 16 bits. (These are the first two bytes of the output, with the second byte being the most significant one.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
double get_CbCr_angle(const char* identifier) {

    unsigned char temp[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char buf[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];

    // initalise with 0s
    memset(buf, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2);
    memset(temp, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    // compute hash into temp
    SHA1((unsigned char *)identifier, strlen(identifier), temp);

    // print from temp into buf and
    // interpret as (signed) chars
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf( (char*) &(buf[i*2]), "%02x", temp[i]);
    }

    printf("SHA1 is %s\n", buf);

    // make a union type of char and float so we can read a char array
    // as float.
    union charFloat {
        float f;
        char s[sizeof(float)];
    };

    union charFloat foo;

    // put first two chars (bytes) into union.
    // bracket notation should be fine since both foo and buf are
    // char arrays.
    foo.s[0] = buf[1];
    foo.s[1] = buf[0];

    printf("interpreted as chars: %s\n", foo.s);
    printf("interpreted as float: %f\n", foo.f);  // 0.000000 - why?

}
```

But I fail to get any reasonable output with this approach. Using more bytes only gives me nonsense values for the `float`, aswell as when interpreting it as an `int`.

Obviously I do not expect anyone to solve this for me. I'd just be very thankful for some tips in what direction to look.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What you are doing will produce extremely small numbers. If you use %g or %a instead of %f, they will print more reasonably.

Comment: Why float?   Why not just `unsigned int sixteen = (temp[1] << 8) + temp[0];`

Comment: @JohnHascall because the next step in the algorithm tells about further computations involving float division by a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at that algorithm:

> 1. Run the input through SHA-1 (RFC 3174 [4]).
> 2. Treat the output as little endian and extract the last-significant 16 bits. (These are the first two bytes of the output, with the second
>      byte being the most significant one.)
> 3. Divide the value by 65536 (use float division) and multiply it by 2π (two Pi).

The algorithm isn't saying to treat the first two bytes as a floating point value.  It says to treat them as a 16-bit integer, then convert the value to a floating point type for the next step.

Also, you should be using `temp` instead of `buf` when converting the values, as `buf` contains printable characters representing hash output while `temp` contains the actual output.

So you would convert the value like this:

```
uint16_t value;
value = temp[0];
value |= temp[1] << 8;
```

Then you cast it to `double` for the next step:

```
double result = value * 2 * M_PI / 65536;
```

Comment: Just so that this doesn't happen to me in the future: How exactly do you infer from the text to interpret the first two bytes as integers? I have read the algorithm over and over again and it did not become clear to me.

Comment: @dbush I would strongly recommend moving the `/ 65536` to the end of that expression so that it does not confuse people into thinking that everything to its right is the divisor.  This also makes the cast unnecessary: `result = value * (2 * M_PI / 65536)` and the usual arithmetic conversions do the Right Thing.

Comment: @ngmir Dividing the extracted value by 65536 only makes sense if the value extracted is being treated as an unsigned 16-bit integer (value range 0 through 65535 inclusive).  Also, we've seen this kind of algorithm before and it's the normal thing you do in them.

Comment: @dbush Uh, I'm not 100% certain but I think the parentheses in my comment are required for the UACs to do the right thing.

Comment: @zwol thank you very much, that that corresponds to the range was outside my active knowledge.

Comment: @zwol Not in this case.  `value` is promoted to `int`.  Multiplying by 2 won't overflow due to the original type of `value`, then multiplying by `M_PI` converts the left side to `double`.

Comment: Good answer, but you are only taking the first byte, since it's the hexadecimal representation of the SHA1 result. `buf[0]` is the first hexa digit, and `buf[1]` is the second. That still makes 16 bits, but with low volatility since it's the hexa chars.

Comment: @RingØ Ahh, I missed that `temp` was the actual SHA1 output and `buf` was a printable version of it.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this by assembling an `uint16_t` from two `char`s using explicit shifts and ORs:

```
uint16_t x = (((uint16_t)(uint8_t)temp[1]) << 8) |
             (((uint18_t)(uint8_t)temp[0]) << 0);
```

The double casts are necessary to ensure that each `char` value is zero- rather than sign-extended to the width of `uint16_t`, before the shift.  Note also that I am reading from `temp`, not `buf` - the *raw* SHA hash, not the hex-coded hash.  Using the hex-coded hash would limit the possible values that `x` could take.

Then, convert `x` to a floating-point number in the range `[0, 1)` by dividing it by 65536:

```
double f = x / 65536.0;
```

65536 is 2<sup>16</sup>; the value range of `uint16_t` is 0 through 65535, inclusive. The `.0` suffix on the divisor is necessary to make C perform floating-point rather than integer division.  For efficiency, this division can be combined with the next step of multiplying by 2π:

```
double f = x * (2 * M_PI / 65536);
```

`M_PI` (declared in `math.h`) is already a floating-point number, so we no longer need a `.0` suffix on 65536, but you need to put parentheses around the entire subexpression `2 * M_PI / 65536` to force the compiler to evaluate that part at compile-time and emit just one runtime multiplication.